# Asp.Net MVC 4 - Adding an object model to an ICollection within another object model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model, icollection

### Some background

I have 2 tables in my Asp.Net MVC 4 Database first application, Submission and Comment. *(There are a great deal more but they are irrelevant for this question)*. Any given Submission can have any number of Comments (One to many) associated to it.

I have a submission details page, on which a user can open a jQuery dialog box with a partial view inside it to add a comment to the submission. This partial view is bound to a strongly typed viewmodel created to add comments.

### Tables/Models

**Submission Table**

Here is the class model for the Submission table. (I have omitted some properties for simplicity).

```
Partial Public Class Submission
    Public Property Submission_ID As Integer
    Public Property Submission_Hash As String
    Public Property Created As Nullable(Of Date)
    Public Property Modified As Date

    Public Overridable Property Comments As ICollection(Of Comment) = New HashSet(Of Comment)
End Class
```

**Comment Table**

And here is the class model for the Comment table. (Again, I have omitted some properties for simplicity).

```
Partial Public Class Comment
    Public Property Comment_ID As Integer
    Public Property User_ID As Nullable(Of Integer)
    Public Property Comment_Type As Nullable(Of Integer)
    Public Property Comment1 As String
    Public Property Created As Nullable(Of Date)
    Public Property Modified As Date

    Public Overridable Property Comment_Type1 As Comment_Type
    Public Overridable Property User As User
    Public Overridable Property Submissions As ICollection(Of Submission) = New HashSet(Of Submission)
End Class
```

### The Requirement

What I am trying to do, is add a new comment to the collection of comments that already exist for a given submission.

### So far...

So far, I have a view model for the add comment dialog box which gets initialised in my controller and then returns the populated view model back to controllers post method. Here is the code

**ViewModel**

```
Public Class SubmissionAddCommentViewModel

    <Display(Name:="Submission")> _
    Public Property Submission_ID As Integer

    <Display(Name:="User")> _
    Public Property User_ID As Integer

    <Display(Name:="Comment type")> _
    Public Property Comment_Type As Integer

    <Required(ErrorMessage:="Please enter a comment.")> _
    <Display(Name:="Comment")> _
    Public Property Comment As String

End Class
```

**ViewModel Builder**

```
Public Class SubmissionAddCommentViewModel_Builder

    Implements IModelBuilder(Of SubmissionAddCommentViewModel, Comment)
    ReadOnly db As GeosightEntities
    ReadOnly submission As Submission

    Public Sub New(db As GeosightEntities, submission As Submission)
        Me.db = db
        Me.submission = submission
    End Sub

    Public Function CreateFrom(entity As Comment) As SubmissionAddCommentViewModel Implements IModelBuilder(Of SubmissionAddCommentViewModel, Comment).CreateFrom
        Dim model = New SubmissionAddCommentViewModel()

        model.Submission_ID = submission.Submission_ID
        model.User_ID = GetLoggedIn_ID()

        Return model
    End Function

    Public Function Rebuild(model As SubmissionAddCommentViewModel) As SubmissionAddCommentViewModel Implements IModelBuilder(Of SubmissionAddCommentViewModel, Comment).Rebuild
        Return model
    End Function

    Public Sub Add(model As SubmissionAddCommentViewModel)
        Dim comment As New Comment

        ' Map the ViewModel and Model fields
        comment.Comment_Type1 = If(IsNothing(model.Comment_Type), Nothing, db.Comment_Type.Find(model.Comment_Type))
        comment.User = db.Users.Find(model.User_ID)
        comment.Comment1 = model.Comment
        comment.Modified = Now

        ' Add the comment
        db.Submissions.Find(model.Submission_ID).Comments.Add(comment)
        db.SaveChanges()
    End Sub

End Class
```

**Controller Get Method**

```
Function AddComment(Optional ByVal id As Integer = Nothing) As ActionResult

    Dim commentAddView As New SubmissionAddCommentViewModel
    Dim submission As Submission = db.Submissions.Find(id)
    Dim comment As New Comment

    If IsNothing(submission) Then
        Return HttpNotFound()
    End If

    Me.builder_AddComment = New SubmissionAddCommentViewModel_Builder(db, submission)

    ' Create the instance of the submission add comment view model
    commentAddView = builder_AddComment.CreateFrom(comment)

    If Request.IsAjaxRequest Then
        Return PartialView("AddCommentPartial", commentAddView)
    End If

    Return View(commentAddView)
End Function
```

**Controller Post method**

```
<HttpPost()> _
Function AddComment(ByVal commentAddView As SubmissionAddCommentViewModel) As ActionResult

    Dim comment As New Comment
    builder_AddComment = New SubmissionAddCommentViewModel_Builder(db, db.Submissions.Find(commentAddView.Submission_ID))

    ' Handle invalid comment models
    If Not ModelState.IsValid Then

        If Request.IsAjaxRequest Then
            Return PartialView("AddCommentPartial", commentAddView)
        End If

        Return View(commentAddView)
    End If

    ' Add the comment
    Me.builder_AddComment.Add(commentAddView)

    ' Display the successful message
    If Request.IsAjaxRequest Then
        Return PartialView("AddCommentSuccessPartial", commentAddView)
    End If

    Return RedirectToAction("Details", New With {.id = commentAddView.Submission_ID})

End Function
```

### Question

When testing the above functionality, execution is successful all the way through to `db.SaveChanges()` in the ViewModel builder, however execution just stops once this line has been run. I have no idea what is happening and as a result am completely stuck.

Does anyone know whether **A)** I am going about adding the comment the right way? **B)** Why this line is stopping execution without any kind of error?

---

### Update

Thank you to Peter Smith for his suggestion of putting a Try Catch around the code, I dont know why I didn't think of or do that in the first place.

I am now getting the follwing error:

> {MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(SELECT" & vbLf & "      `Submission_Comment`.`Submission_ID`, " & vbLf & "      `Submission_Comment`.' at line 1" & vbCrLf & "   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket()" & vbCrLf & "   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetResult(Int32& affectedRow, Int64& insertedId)" & vbCrLf & "   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.GetResult(Int32 statementId, Int32& affectedRows, Int64& insertedId)" & vbCrLf & "   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResult(Int32 statementId, Boolean force)" & vbCrLf & "   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult()" & vbCrLf & "   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)" & vbCrLf & "   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader()" & vbCrLf & "   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()" & vbCrLf & "   at MySql.Data.Entity.EFMySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()" & vbCrLf & "   at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.DynamicUpdateCommand.Execute(UpdateTranslator translator, EntityConnection connection, Dictionary`2 identifierValues, List`1 generatedValues)" & vbCrLf & "   at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update(IEntityStateManager stateManager, IEntityAdapter adapter)}

Comment: Try (sic) adding a try catch block around the db section in your Add method; this should give you more detail on the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find the problem and implement a solution. In order to help others who might come across the same issue as me, here was my solution.

In my MySQL schema,  the intermediate table (Submission_Comment) between the Submission and Comment tables has 2 columns...Submission_ID and Comment_ID.

When I set up the tables, I made these columns Foreign keys but forgot to make them a composite primary key. **Making the 2 columns a composite primary key fixed my issue.**